# Javascript execution in browser

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, webbrowser-control

This might sound silly, but has got me bugged for the past couple of days. I just wanted some clarity on how javascript is interpreted and executed in a browser, esp during event handling. Suppose i have two functions based on a click event for the same element. Might be two different event listeners written for two different classes, and the same element has both these classes during the click. Which function does the js executer run first?

Does the interpreter interpret the complete js file on event being triggered or use a bytecode generated during interpretation as in Java or specifically execute lines x - x+y?

Rather than knowing if function 1 would execute before function 2 or vice versa, i am more curious about the mechanism behind the whole process of registering and handling events using js.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512551/the-order-of-multiple-event-listeners

Comment: @gurvinder372 Bro, please see edit to the question. I can actuually fiind out the order of execution by trigerring console logs. i need to know the mechanism behind it. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i am more curious about the mechanism behind the whole process of
>   registering and handling events using js.

Think of it as a queue where events are getting pushed when you do `element.addEventListener`.

Queue has a property -> **First-In-First-Out**.

So, which ever event-listener has been added to the queue first (basically received by the event-target first) will be executed first, until all of them are executed.

Note: If the same event-handler method is [added more than once](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners) (same parameters to addEventListener), then older one is replaced by new one.

**Secondly**, When we add the event via `addEventListener` we [specify a boolean value](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) called - `useCapture`. If the value is true, then events assigned to parent element is fired first and child-elements later, and vice-versa if this value is false.

Comment: As silly as it sounds, does the interpreter interpret the complete js file on event being triggered or use a bytecode generated during interpretation as in Java or specifically execute lines x - x+y?

Comment: @KevinSunny `does the interpreter interpret the complete js file on event being triggered` complete js is interpreted when the JS is loaded and interpretation only does the loading of funciton, not their execution. Individual functions are interpreted when they are invoked.

Comment: Okay... so if i have a frequently used function, in a large js file, is there any advantage if i write the function in the beginning?